# create a new instance inside a method, and it remains outside method

Tags: java, object, reference

look at this example:

```
Class Car{
  private Chassis  chassis;
  private Engine engine;

  public Car(Engine engine){  //passing a object that is instantiated outside the class
    this.engine = engine;       
  }

  public void foo(){
      chassis = new  Chassis(engine);
  }
  public void print(){
     System.out.println(chassis);
  }

  public setEngine(Engine engine){
     this.engine = engine;    
  }
 }

class CarPark{
 private Car car;

 public CarPark(Car car){
    this.car = car;

 }     
public void doSometing(){
    Engine engine = new Engine();
    car.setEngine(engine);
 }

}
```

some considerations :

- if i call `foo()` ,new instance of **Chassis** is created as a parameter an `engine` object,***and the reference of the new object  created also remains outside method right?***

  - for example:

    if i call  method `print()` after calling `foo()` it will print the memory address of  the new object `Chassis` created?
- if i call `doSomething()` a new `Engine` is created and immediately i call `setEngine`, and in this case, ***the engine "pointer" of the class car points to the new instance I created***:

  - *The old engine "pointer" is  carbage collected*
  - *And now the reference is  the new instance created*
  - *and if I call back foo, a new chassis is created with a new instance of the engine?*

all these considerations are correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if i call foo() ,new instance of Chassis is created as a parameter an
>   engine object,and the reference of the new object created also remains
>   outside method right?
>
> for example:
>
> if i call method print() after calling foo() it will print the memory
>   address of the new object Chassis created?

Yes as far as both method will be invoked on the same instance of Car, You can try that.

`chassis` is an instance field of `Car` class, and inside `foo()` method, you are creating an instance of `Chassis` and assign it to instance field `chassis`

> if i call doSomething() a new Engine is created and immediately i call
>   setEngine, and in this case, the engine "pointer" of the class car
>   points to the new instance I created:
>
> The old engine "pointer" is carbage collected And now the reference is
>   the new instance created and if I call back foo, a new chassis is
>   created with a new instance of the engine?

Bit correction there, reference are not Garbage Collected, only object are Garbage Collected. When you assign a object to a reference, the previous object will be GGed, if it doesn't have any live reference.

Comment: ok, so it will print both address memory,understood.Regards other considerations @Abimaran Kugathasan.

Comment: and in this case it the entire old object chassis, can be deleted?,naturally after calling doSomething() because, as you can see there is no strong reference for that object, and a new instance can be created well @Abimaran Kugathasan

Comment: @Cimat : I don't get you.

Comment: if i call `doSomething()` a new Engine is created and immediately i call `setEngine()` ,if I call back `foo`, a new chassis is created with a new instance of the `engine` i want to know if in the case above this situation will happen. @Abimaran Kugathasan

Comment: @Cimat : If you call back foo after setEngine(), new Chassis object will be created with same engine which you passed.

Comment: i' m agree with you, but you missed a point ,i call `setEngine()` inside `doSomething()`, my dubt is here.. then i call `foo()` the chassis is created with the new instance of `engine` created inside `doSomething()`, or remains the old chassis? @Abimaran Kugathasan